# get individual value from post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

```js
var payments = {
  totalamount: totalamount

}
$.post("target.php", {
    data: payments
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    window.open('target.php');
  });
```

```
if (array_key_exists('data', $_POST)) {
   echo "next line is post";
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

I have the js inside done function of ajax request.
The php is in target.php.

In network > XHR > response

```
next line is postArray
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [totalamount] => 190
        )

)
```

This result is for target.php

> How can I get the value of post individually.

I want to get able to get value like

```
echo $_POST['totalamount']
```

Comment: `$_POST['data']['totalamount']`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the post the way you do, you have to access the totalamount variable by doing this:

```
$_POST['data']['totalamount']
```

Or you can change your $.post to this, and it will work the way you want it to
What you've done, is to put your totalamount into data, but that seems like a waste.

```
$.post("target.php", payments)
.done(function(data) {
    window.open('target.php');
});
```